# How can I consistently move in the behaviors FollowPath (libgdx)?

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I consistently move in the behaviors FollowPath, what I need to set the parameters in this behavior, my actor was tossed from one side to the other.
At the moment the actor moves as shown in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfAn1.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
linePath = new LinePath<>(wayPoints, isPathOpen);
FollowPath<Vector2, LinePath.LinePathParam> followPathSB = new FollowPath<>(character, linePath ,30f) //
    .setTimeToTarget(0.1f) //
    .setArrivalTolerance(0.001f) //
    .setDecelerationRadius(80);
character.setSteeringBehavior(followPathSB);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
With these settings, the path will be stable at any speed of the actor.

linePath = new LinePath<>(wayPoints, isPathOpen); FollowPath followPathSB = new FollowPath<>(character, linePath ,100f) 
                .setDecelerationRadius(350)
                .setLimiter(new LinearLimiter(3500, 1000));